# why do we consider "skipping the steps" as "failed steps" with karate.abort() in karate report?

Tags: dsl, karate

For my tests scenarios i am using "karate.abort()" function and this skips the steps beneath it if the condition is fulfilled.
But this is marking my complete test as failed because of the skipped steps .

Is there any way to mark the test case as PASSED if the karate.abort() is called and next steps are skipped?

Example:

Scenario Outline: Lambda API registration when ARN is invalid

```
Given url ApiAdminURL

And path AdminPath

And header apigateway-apikey = apiGatewayKey

And header apigateway-basepath = 'lambda-migration'

* json myReq = read('swagger-lambda.json')

* set myReq.apiConf.subscriptionTiers = <subscriptionTiers>

* set myReq.swagger.info.title = 'REGTEST_AUTO_Regression_Lambda_Quote_Function'

* set myReq.swagger.basePath = 'lambda-migration'

* set myReq.swagger.info.version = 'v1'

* set myReq.swagger.x-lambda-arn = '<arn>'

And request myReq

When method post

Then status <responseCode>

* eval if (responseStatus == 400) karate.abort()

* call read('Lambda-Sleep.feature')

* call read('Lambda-APIDefinition.feature')

* def responsefromsubscriber = call read('Lambda-Subscriber.feature')

 {accessTokenforInvokation: '#(accessTokenforInvokation)', applicationId: '#

 (applicationId)', subscribeToken: '#(subscribeToken)'}

* def AccessTokenforInvokation =

  responsefromsubscriber.accessTokenforInvokation

* def ApplicationId = responsefromsubscriber.applicationId

* def SubscribeToken = responsefromsubscriber.subscribeToken
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug that was fixed in a patch release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/464

Can you just upgrade your Karate version to 0.8.0.1 and try again.

Comment: Tried upgrading the version ot 0.8.0.1 in pom.xml as shown below:
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.version>3.6.0</maven.compiler.version>
        <karate.version>0.8.0.1</karate.version>
    </properties>

Comment: But the build is failing with error :
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myproject: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.mycompany:myproject:jar:0.8.0.1: Failed to collect dependencies at com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:jar:0.8.0.1: Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:jar:0.8.0.1: Could not transfer artifact com.intuit.karate:karate-apache:pom:0.8.0.1 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Connect to repo.maven.apache.org:443 [repo.maven.apache.org/151.101.24.215] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]

Comment: @SnehaShukla sorry, must be some network or proxy problem in your env: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.intuit.karate/karate-apache/0.8.0.1